# is infinite union of finite sets compact?

Tags: sequences-and-series, compactness

I'm having a hard time solving this one for my HW: 
if $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is any collection of subsets of $\mathbb R$ with each set $A_n$ contains finitely many numbers, then the infinite union of the $A_n$ is closed and bounded.

Does finitely many elements mean that for example $A_n=\{n,n+1\}$? How can I prove or disprove this? Any hint?

Comment: A very general strategy for recognizing the answer is *false* (before being able to prove it) applies here. Namely: *Every* set can be written as a (usually infinite) union of singleton sets— which, in particular, contain finitely many numbers. So if the statement were true, then *every* set would be compact, and hence the concept of compactness would be meaningless. [Note that in research math, one will frequently encounter meaningless definitions, because one doesn't know what the "right" definitions are yet! But in as well-trodden a part of math as basic topology, this won't happen much.]

Comment: (For the sake of completeness: one must exercise a little caution when applying this strategy. It may be simply that a concept is meaningless because the "context" you are considering is too narrow. For instance, every subset of a finite (discrete) set is, indeed, compact! So this really is only a strategy for getting a good *guess* at the answer.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $A_n = \{n\}$ for $n \in \mathbb N$. Is $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n$ closed and bounded?

Comment: it divegrges to infinity so it can't be bounded, but I believe it's closed since the complement R\S is open and it contains it's boundary points. right?

Comment: Yes, it is closed since its complement is open. And since the sequence $(n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is unbounded the set $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n$ isn't bounded as well. So in general the infinite union of compact sets is not compact. Good job :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please check an answer if you have no further questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. For example, taking $A_n=\{n\}$ would result in a union which is unbounded, and hence not compact. Alternatively, letting $A_n=\{1/n\}$ would yield a union that is not closed (it has a limit point 0, but does not contain it).

In each case the infinite union of finite sets is not compact.

Comment: thank you. that was helpful